# What is the difference between "disbursement" and "expense"

Tags: meaning

My little pedantic friend introduced me a word, ***disbursement***, saying it is his way of expressing a word, ***expense***. I asked him the difference between them, but he could not answer it... What is the difference between them? Is it just a fancier expression?

Comment: Have you checked dictionary definitions? If so, why did they not help?

Comment: @Yunhee Try using a dictionary.

Comment: Everyone should have a little pedantic friend. +1 for that reference.

Comment: The result of a disbursement is that your bank account balance decreases (or you have less bank notes in your wallet). The reason for disbursement may be an expense, but also a deposit, a loan, a transfer to another account, etc.

Comment: @Graffito Wow, your explanation is way more helpful than dictionaries or accounting books. I want to boast in front of him, really...But I won't do that. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are not the same. *Disbursement* has a more specific meaning and refers to a process of paying money from a *fund* (collected for a particular purpose):

> 1. an amount of money that is paid from a fund
> 2. the process of paying money from a fund

([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/disbursement))

Answer (score 1):

A disbursement is spent money that has been, well, dispersed.  An expense is a reason to spend money on something that is, well, expensive.

> **Expense**
>
> The cost required for something; the money spent on something.
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=expense&oq=expense&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

> **Disbursement**
>
> A noun that describes the spending or distributing of money
>
> [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=disbursement&oq=disbursement&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)

They can mean the same thing.  But they can be as different as a $50 bill and a bill for $50.